# Thread will not execute run() when condition is met

Tags: java

I have a Java program that is simulating one way tunnel. A semaphore represents the tunnel, and there are two threads that represent the queues of traffic waiting on either side to pass through. In main, both threads are started as well as a thread to generate cars on either side every second. When a thread realizes its queue has cars in it, it attempts to acquire the semaphore. Once it has it, it allows each car to pass through, and releases the semaphore for the other side to use.

My problem is that it only is able to pass cars on the first try. After one side has claimed and released the semaphore, it seems that it will not be able to send cars through again. It seems to be that the if statement that is checking for cars in the queue is not executing.

```
class leftManager extends Thread {
private int leftQueue = 0;
private int total = 0;
static Semaphore semaphore;

public leftManager(Semaphore semaphore) {
    this.semaphore = semaphore;
    this.leftQueue = leftQueue;
}
public int getQueue() {
    return leftQueue;
}
public void setQueue(int x) {
    leftQueue += x;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            if (leftQueue > 0) {
                System.out.println("Catch");
                semaphore.acquire();
                for (int i = 1; i <= leftQueue; i++) {
                    int temp = (leftQueue - (leftQueue - (i - 1)));
                    leftBoundPass pass = new leftBoundPass((temp * 2) + total);
                    pass.start();
                    try {
                        leftManager.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                total += leftQueue;
                leftQueue = 0;
                semaphore.release();
                System.out.println("release");
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The rightManager is identical, other than different variable names and a different "boundPass" thread for the cars.

```
class leftBoundPass extends Thread {
private int car;
public leftBoundPass(int car) {
    this.car = car;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Left-bound car " + car + " is in the tunnel.");
    //This is one second of sleep
    try {
        leftBoundPass.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Left-bound car " + car + " is exiting the tunnel.");
}
}
```

The car generator is as follows:class trafficGenerator extends Thread {

```
leftManager left;
rightManager right;

public trafficGenerator(leftManager left, rightManager right) {
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    int random;
    
    while (true) {
        random = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
        
        if (random == 0) {
            System.out.println("Left-bound car wants to enter the tunnel");
            left.setQueue(1);
            //System.out.println(left.getQueue());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Right-bound car wants to enter the tunnel");
            right.setQueue(1);
        }
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
        }       
    }   
}
}
```

Output:

```
Left-bound car wants to enter the tunnel
Catch
Left-bound car 0 is in the tunnel.
Left-bound car 0 is exiting the tunnel.
release
Left-bound car wants to enter the tunnel
Right-bound car wants to enter the tunnel
Right-bound car wants to enter the tunnel
```

Comment: Just through a quick read-through, `leftQueue` is read & modified across threads without any synchronization, so you have a data race. This may cause your bug, if one thread is writing `leftQueue = 1` but the other thread doesn't see that write. One way to solve that would be to make `leftQueue` a `volatile` field. Another would be to check it _after_ you acquire the semaphore (since acquiring it establishes a happens-before between the last release).

Comment: Now that I'm reading it a bit more carefully, you're reading and writing `leftQueue` from outside the semaphore's acquire-release (in the get/set methods), so it's just a full-on data race. You should use an `AtomicInteger` or `synchronized` (`volatile` isn't enough, because it doesn't solve the `+=` race.)

Comment: My good friend yshavit, that appears to have made some sort of progress. I have no idea what a volatile field is but that made some progress with it. Not sure if that is the complete fix but it is definitely a step forward. I wish you all the best. Will update if that fixes it!

Comment: Multithreading code is _really_ hard to figure out by experimentation, because it plays out probabilisticly/randomly almost by definition. I would highly suggest a more comprehensive approach to learning it. I read Java Concurrency In Practice, which I highly recommend (it's a bit dated now in terms of the high-level constructs it talks about, but the main thing it teaches is about how to think about concurrency), though I'm sure there are other good resources out there.